# Unix Fork Understanding

Tags: posix, fork

I am learning [process forking](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unixprocess.html) and I'm trying the code of listing 3:

```
sunbox$ cat fork2.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

        pid_t p;

        printf("Original program, pid=%d\n", getpid());
        p = fork();
        if (p == 0) {
                printf("In child process, pid=%d, ppid=%d\n",
                        getpid(), getppid());
        } else {
                printf("In parent, pid=%d, fork returned=%d\n",
                        getpid(), p);
        }
}

sunbox$ gcc fork2.c -o fork2
sunbox$ ./fork2
Original program, pid=767
In child process, pid=768, ppid=767
In parent, pid=767, fork returned=768
```

The output I get:

> ```
> Original program, pid=2728 
> In parent, pid=2728, fork returned=2731
> In child process, pid=2731, ppid=2728
> ```

Whereas the sample page shows an output of child first, and then parent? I don't understand this.

Also, when I run the code in my college lab I get output as shown on the page. Thanks a lot in advance for troubling to answer this naive question.

If it matters, I'm running Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: A better place to ask POSIX related questions is [unix.se](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I've put the code you were discussing in the question for you.

Comment: @faif: Since it's related to POSIX software development, I think it belongs here on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the [fork()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) system call, it is up to the OS scheduler which process continues first. It is possible that repeated runs of this same program would result in different orders.

This is called [non-determinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm).